# How to prepare data including cardinal directions to work with rayleigh.test {circular}

Tags: r, statistics

I have data in a form like this:

```
quantity direction
10 n
5 e
6 ne
12 n
20 nw
5 s
8 n
1 sw
3 se
2 ne
6 nw
8 n
2 se
3 e
4 w
9 nw
```

on which I want to run the `rayleigh.test` from `circular` package (For more information why I want to do this check: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198701/check-for-significant-difference-between-numbers-of-sightings-per-cardinal-direc). I guess that I have to use the `circular` function up front to prepare the data but I have no clue how to do that. The allowed values for the units argument of this function are “radians”, “degrees”, “hours” and I can't figure out how to fit my directions into that.

**How can I get `rayleigh.test` to accept cardinal directions as input?**

Answer (score 0):

I can't judge whether the rayleigh test is ok with non-continuous data, but here is a small example of how to map your characters to degrees:

```
df <- data.frame( quantity = c(37,5,6)  , direction = c("n", "ne" , "n") )

df$direction <- as.factor(df$direction)
# create a map from character to degrees:
map <- setNames( c( 0, 45) , c("n", "ne") )

levels(df$direction) <- map[ levels(df$direction) ]
```